# Can I remove products in a batch from category?

Tags: category, products

I want to remove ~300 skus, a solution might be to remove everything and then add the skus I want, but I was thinking it might be an easier way... Can anyone help?

Answer (score -3):

UPDATE 27.07.2019:

1. Select all products that you want to remove from cat.(maybe applay filter by sku from to) , edit attribute visible to only "Catalog" (or any attribute like price, status or even name that will help You filter products in cat.))
2. Go to edit category page => edit => in "Products in Category" change filter - first column to yes and Visibility to 'Catalog'
3. Untick all.

Helpfull links
Free extension for filter by category in product list
https://github.com/utklasad/magento2-admin-product-grid-category-filter

Comment: my category has more than skus, i want to remove specific skus, i don't want to remove all prods...

Comment: I change answer, I dont know why I put such a answer before